# print selected value in dropdown in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, continuous-integration, dropdown

Okay so I recently Swtiched from PHP to Codeigniter. I am newbie to CI framework.This is my PHP Code:

```
<td>
                  <?php 
                  include 'template_category.php';
                   $categoryList = fetchCategoryTree();
                    ?>
                   <select name="make">
                    <?php foreach($categoryList as $cl) 
                    { 
                      if($cl["id"]!==$PRODUCTCATEGORY)
                        {
                          echo "Hey Matched!";
                        }
                        else
                        {?>
                          <option selected value="<?php echo $cl["id"] ?>"><?php echo $cl["name"]; ?></option>  
                        <?php }

                      ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $cl["id"] ?>"><?php echo $cl["name"]; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </select>
              </td>
```

Now how can I Convert into CI's syntax. I mean I don't know how to give conditions inside Dropdown.

```
<tr>
    <td align="right"><? echo form_label('Category');?></td>
    <?php $this->load->view('template_category'); $options= array(''=>'',''=>'');$categoryList = fetchCategoryTree(); ?>
    <td><? echo form_dropdown(array('id' =>'address','name' =>'address' )); ?><br/></td>
</tr>
```

How can I make my CI code works like ditto As Above mentioned PHP.
Deeply: I don't know how to give conditions inside dropdown in CI.

Comment: what is ditto? ..

Comment: I mean exactly same

Comment: refer https://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Comment: You can use the third parameter by passing the value of selected option in form_dropdown function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you. For further reference
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html

```
<?php 
include 'template_category.php';
$categoryList = fetchCategoryTree();
$select_values = array();
foreach($categoryList as $cl){
    $select_values[$cl["id"]] = $cl["name"];
}
echo form_dropdown('make', $select_values, $PRODUCTCATEGORY);
?>
```